# How can I create a function in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a 3 separate functions out of this big chunk of code. One to work out the alphabetical order of keys in a dictionary, one to work out the highest scores for values in a dictionary and one to find the average score from a dictionary

These are the three dictionaries:

```
class_1={"Mike":[2,3,2,5,3],"Jack":[1,2,1,6,4],"Rob":[0,2,6,4]}
class_2={"Steve":[2,5,2,5,9],"Mo":[3,2,1,6,4],"Bill":[9,2,6,4]}
class_3={"Harry":[1,3,1,5,3],"Dave":[7,2,1,6,4],"Molly":[3,2,9,4]}
```

Using this big block of code, I can do what I want to achieve but it doesn't look elegant or efficient.

```
class_choice_menu=input("Please choose the class you would like to check:\n\
1.Class 1\n\
2.Class 2\n\
3.Class 3\n")
class_choice=int(class_choice_menu)
if class_choice ==1:
    class_1_average = {key: int(sum(value)/len(value)) for key, value in class_1.items()}
    max_each_1 = {key: max(value) for key, value in class_1.items()}
    print("Alphabetically")
    for key in sorted(max_each_1.keys()):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, max_each_1[key]))
    print ('\nSort by average scores(descending order):')
    for key, value in sorted(class_1_average.items(), reverse = True, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, class_1_average[key]))
    print ('\nSort by high scores(descending order):')
    for key, value in sorted(max_each_1.items(), reverse = True, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, max_each_1[key]))        
elif class_choice ==2:
    class_2_average = {key: int(sum(value)/len(value)) for key, value in class_2.items()}
    max_each_2 = {key: max(value) for key, value in class_2.items()}
    print("Alphabetically")
    for key in sorted(max_each_2.keys()):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, max_each_2[key]))
    print ('\nSort by average scores(descending order):')
    for key, value in sorted(class_2_average.items(), reverse = True, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, class_2_average[key]))
    print ('\nSort by high scores(descending order):')
    for key, value in sorted(max_each_2.items(), reverse = True, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, max_each_2[key])) 
elif class_choice ==3:
    class_3_average = {key: int(sum(value)/len(value)) for key, value in class_3.items()}
    max_each_3 = {key: max(value) for key, value in class_3.items()}
    print("Alphabetically")
    for key in sorted(max_each_3.keys()):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, max_each_3[key]))
    print ('\nSort by average scores(descending order):')
    for key, value in sorted(class_3_average.items(), reverse = True, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, class_3_average[key]))
    print ('\nSort by high scores(descending order):')
    for key, value in sorted(max_each_3.items(), reverse = True, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, max_each_3[key]))
```

I had a go at one but it didn't seem to work

```
def alphabetical(class_choice):
    max_each_%s= {key:max(value) for key,value in class_%s.items()} 
    print("Alphabetically")
    for key in sorted (max_each_%s.keys()):
        print("%s: %s" % (key,max_each_%s[key] % class_choice))
```

Comment: If you're having problems, please tell us what is wrong - what error message do you get, or what output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you need.

First you need to understand how to define a function.

> A function is a block of organized, reusable code that is used to perform a single, related action. Functions provide better modularity for your application and a high degree of code reusing.

Let's look your code.

I suggest that you will want to extend class variable , it's easy to maintenance. It can base on user input and if-else statement to return that you select.

```
def get_class(num):
    if num == 1:
        return class_1
    elif num == 2:
        return class_2
    elif num == 3:
        return class_3
```

In order to simply your code. We can reuse this code to use.

```
def calculate(selected_class):
    class_average = {key: int(sum(value)/len(value)) for key, value in selected_class.items()}
    max_each_student = {key: max(value) for key, value in selected_class.items()}
    return (class_average, max_each_student)

def Alphabetically(max_each_student):
    print("Alphabetically")
    for key in sorted(max_each_student.keys()):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, max_each_student[key]))

def sort_by_average_scores(average):
    print ('\nSort by average scores(descending order):')
    for key, value in sorted(average.items(), reverse = True, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, average[key]))

def sort_by_high_scores(max_each_student):
    print ('\nSort by high scores(descending order):')
    for key, value in sorted(max_each_student.items(), reverse = True, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])):
        print ("%s: %s" % (key, max_each_student[key]))
```

When you want to process data, you just use these function. It can do the same.

```
the_class = get_class(class_choice)
the_class_average, max_each_student_of_the_class= calculate(the_class)
Alphabetically(max_each_student_of_the_class)
sort_by_average_scores(the_class_average)
sort_by_high_scores(max_each_student_of_the_class)
```